# Filtering by Time in a WFS GetFeature request

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getfeature

I have a WMS layer that uses a 'time' dimension parameter to filter the view by time. I want to perform WFS GetFeature requests against this layer, taking into account the 'time' value.

I can do this by passing a relevant filter into the WFS query, like this

`<PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>year</PropertyName><Literal>1974-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo>`

However, this assumes that I already know the name of the property that is being used as the 'time' dimension. I need a way to discover what that property name is, as I do not know it in advance. Note I cannot use WMS GetFeatureInfo as I need to do complex polygon intersect queries.

I can use DescribeFeatureType to get a list of properties, and pick the one that is a date/time, but what if there are multiple date/time columns? I have no way of discovering which one is the correct one to filter by.

Ultimately my question is:

- is there a way to discover which property name of a layer is being used as the 'time' dimension
- or can I somehow just pass something similar to 'time' directly into the WFS request and have the server work it out for me.

Tagged with GeoServer as that is the primary server I will be using, but ideally this should be OGC standard.

Comment: You'd need to look at the metadata I guess

Comment: GetCapabilities and DescribeFeatureType are the means that WFS standard provides. If that is not enough you must try to contact the service provider and ask. Contact info should be in GetCapabilities.

Comment: So this is what you get from a GetCapabilities `<Dimension name="time" default="2101-01-01T00:00:00Z" units="ISO8601">1583-01-01T00:00:00.000Z/2101-01-01T00:00:00.000Z/PT1S</Dimension>`. It just says 'time'. DescribeFeatureType lists all the properties, but I don't know which one is being used for 'time'. If there is is only one, I can make an assumption, but if there are multiple date/time fields, there is no way of knowing. If that's the case, that's fine, I just didn't want to miss something obvious

Comment: You need GetCapabilities to get the feature type name(s), then DescribeFeatureType to get the structure of the relevant type.  Or you could just use DescribeFeatureType without specifying typename and get information for all feature types provided by the service.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274529/wms-and-wfs-time-search-criterion-dimension and https://www.mail-archive.com/geoserver-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg34751.html. WFS is missing the direct time-as-a-dimension support and you have not missed anything obvious.